# Check class creation in OrientDB

Tags: python, python-2.7, orientdb, pyorient

I'm trying to create classes with `pyorient` driver but sometime if class exists I got class exists message. Is there a way to check whether class is exists or not in OrientDB python driver? Here is part of my sample code for class creation...

```
@classmethod
def create(cls):

    cls._cluster_id = OrientEngine.client.command("CREATE CLASS %s EXTENDS V" % cls.__name__)
    return cls._cluster_id
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Via SQL to check the existence of "OUser" class execute this:

```
SELECT FROM ( SELECT expand( classes ) FROM metadata:schema ) WHERE name = 'OUser'
```

Via Java API:

```
OClass cls = db.getMetadata().getSchema().getClass("OUser");
```

Comment: any idea on how to do that with the Java API?